# How to tell if it's Carbon or Cocoa?

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

I'm confused; how can I tell if a window is created for carbon or cocoa by just looking at the c++ code?

How can I see the difference between a carbon and a cocoa window, is it carbon = WindowRef and Cocoa = NSView?? How can I tell the difference by just looking at the code?

Would like to know the answer so that I can see the differences in APIs like VST GUI 4.0 etc.

I would really like to have a guidance here.

Comment: Cocoa is an Objective-C API.

Comment: @dandan78 and if it's carbon that is deprecated since OSX version >= 10.8 it will not work on these machines and cocoa will not work on the earlier machines?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for Carbon API - C++ and Cocoa - Objective C.
In general Carbon used very time ago and if the source code don't uses libraries like QT or wxWidgets and project on C++ - it's Carbon. 
Also you can search in source code for including framework < Cocoa/Cocoa.h > If yes - then its Cocoa/

Also next URL may help you https://superuser.com/questions/445598/how-do-i-tell-if-ive-carbon-or-cocoa-installed-on-my-mac

Comment: Ok so if I find a carbon include the API is not going to work on OSX 10.8 and later?

Comment: Likely no. It make work some time even if methods marked as deprecated but apple may remove methods in next release. So it's a good chance to make replacement of deprecated methods. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/CarbonCoreDeprecations/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012224 may help you.

Comment: So nothing has been removed yet? Carbon is still working on the latest OSX machines? Thanks for the link by the way.